# Put Multiple Plots on a Single Page in R with spplot?

Tags: r, plot

I know how to plot two plots when using the simple function plot:

```
 old.par <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
 plot(faithful, main="Faithful eruptions")
 plot(large.islands, main="Islands", ylab="Area")
 par(old.par)
```

this would return sth like:

[image]

I need to do the same for a fairly complex spplot function. What I'd like to have is a 3 x 3 square.

The function I want to plot 9 times is:

```
labelat = fivenum(gwr.res$SDF$Unempl)
labeltext = labelat 


spplot(gwr.res$SDF, "Unempl", cuts = 4, at = c(fivenum(gwr.res$SDF$Unempl)),     col.regions = Greens,
    colorkey=list(width=0.3,      
              space="right", 
              tick.number=5, 
              labels=list(  
                at=labelat, 
                labels=labeltext )))
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `grid.arrange` from package `gridExtra`. Doing `grid.arrange(spplot(..),spplot(...),spplot(.....))` and so on will arrange them in a grid.

Here's an example using the `meuse` data set that generates 9 such plots and then uses `do.call` to save having to do `grid.arrange(plots[[1], plots[[2]],` and so on up to 9:

```
> require(gridExtra)
> plots = lapply(names(meuse)[1:9], function(.x) spplot(meuse,.x))
> do.call(grid.arrange,plots)
```

[image: 3x3 grid]

Answer (score 9):

Or even simpler:

```
grid.arrange(spplot(df.voro2, "my.data", xlab = "x", ylab = "y", main = "my title") , 
             spplot(df.voro, "dummy", xlab = "x2", ylab = "y2", main = "my title2" ))
```

[image]

Comment: You can specify `ncol = 2` to make them side-by-side.